# Radio button will not change from "optionA" - AJAX / JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I am trying to parse this form to php -> mysql. My problem is var g in AJAX. it is always the top input option and isn't responsive to the users choice. DB will always show "f" in this instance. Any ideas?

```
  <input id="gender" type="radio" name="gender" value="f">Female
  <input id="gender" type="radio" name="gender" value="m">Male

  <input id="signupbtn"  onclick="signup()" type="submit" value="Sign Up">
    <span id="status"></span>
</form>

function signup(){
    var g = _("gender").value;
```

Comment: Would you like to pick the selected value of a radio button?

Comment: Yes the user selected value. But it will always default to the first DOM input, "f" in this example.

Comment: You have used same id for both radio buttons, Can we use the ID attribute twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an `id` is supposed to be unique for elements on the page.  Because of this (and, I believe, depending on the browser) it looks like getElementById() is only returning the first element of that id.  To counter this, you can try:

```
var theRadio=document.getElementsByName("gender");
for (var I=0; I<theRadio.length; I++){
    if (theRadio[I].checked){
        var g=theRadio[I].value;
        break;
    }
}
```

That should work - looping through and checking.

Comment: Cheers!  You didn't specify jQuery or not, so I stuck with vanilla code.  There are more succinct ways of writing it if you're using jQuery. EDIT: I guess it's one of the tags.  Vanilla code anyway. ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Use this for g value**  **look at here [JsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/mohalibala/kT2ff/)**

```
$("#signupbtn").click(function ()
                      {
    var g= "";
    var selected = $("input[type='radio']:checked");
    if (selected.length > 0) {
    g= selected.val();
}
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
 $('input:radio[name=sex]:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this is in working condition:

```
function signup() {

        var isRadioBtnChecked = $('input:radio[name=gender]').is(':checked');
        if (isRadioBtnChecked) {
        var selectedGender = $('input:radio[name=gender]:checked').val();
        }
    }
```

Thanks.